# Java parsing webpages in background

Tags: java

I need to access all links from a bookmark (in a Java program).
I know how to take the links from bookmark, but I don't have any idea how to open every links (in background) and search then from some word-keys.

For example, I take http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20151009-where-is-the-windiest-place-on-earth from bookmarks, and I want to parse the page from that location (but without open in web browser) to find how many times appear the word "north".

May someone help me?

Comment: this simplest way would be [using URLs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: I found on "using URLs" site subchapter "Reading Directly from a URL". Thanks for that point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some Java library that understand DOM. Try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I remeber that I used once JSoup library, but, in my opinion, the greatest method is to read directly from URL, because it doesn't need any 3rd party library and source-code can be faster. Thanks for your feedback ;)